# How to pass IOption into IServiceCollection (Best Practice) in .NET 6

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, ioptionsmonitor

I have a appsettings.json with below:

```
{
  "$schema": "./appsettings-schema.json",  
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "dbDSN": "Server=.;Database=demodb;User Id=demo;Password=123",    
  },
  "ConnectPoint": {
    "siteAPI": "https://workersite.com/api"
  }
}
```

The class as below :

```
public record SiteConfiguration {
    public ConnectPoint ConnectPoint { get; set; };
}
public record ConnectPoint {
    public string siteAPI { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

and I create static class ServiceInjection like

```
public static class ServiceInjection {
    public static IServiceCollection AddConnectServices(this IServiceCollection services, IOptions<SiteConfiguration> configuration) {
        
        services.AddSingleton<IAPIClient>(
            new APIClient(              
                    new HttpClient {
                        BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.Value.ConnectPoint.siteAPI)
                    }));
        return services;
    }
}
```

In the startup.cs, under ConfigureServices()
It can be work as below code:

```
services.Configure<SiteConfiguration>();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var opt = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SiteConfiguration>>().Value;
services.AddConnectServices(opt.value);
```

But I want to change Ioptionmonitor and don't want to use services.BuildServiceProvider() in dotnet6, can I know how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried bundling everything in one extension method to provide `IOptions`/`IOptionsMonitor` with the inline `ServiceProvider` (`sp`)

```cs
public static class ServiceInjection 
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddConnectServices(this IServiceCollection services) {
        
        services.Configure<SiteConfiguration>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAPIClient>(sp =>
        {
            var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SiteConfiguration>>();
            var client = new APIClient(              
                    new HttpClient {
                        BaseAddress = new Uri(options.Value.ConnectPoint.siteAPI)
                    });

        }
        return services;
    }
}
```

... or to improve one step forward use it with [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) like this instead of creating the `HttpClient` by yourself:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IAPIClient, APIClient>();
services.AddSingleton<IAPIClient, APIClient>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly just pass IConfiguration to AddConnectServices and read it manually.

Another option, you could create a wrapper around the HttpClient e.g. IMyHttpClient, and then in its implementation's constructor you would take in IOptions<SiteConfiguration> and the [IHttpClientFactory (how to setup)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/http-client#basic-usage) and use the factory to get the HttpClient in your MyHttpClient implementation (so it's lifetime is managed properly, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/httpclient-guidelines) about that, especially if you go with newing it yourself).

You could implement SendAsync which just passes the request along and returns it. Could also be a nice place to have some logging for all your request/responses, or that could even be on a decorator for your IMyHttpClient.